# When I get json data from URL its show me nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In the console, they show the array but when I want to show them on my HTML page its shows nothing. I want to get data from the URL(https://my-json-server.typicode.com/journeymanavi/mock-json-api/posts
) & show the data on the HTML page.

```
$.getJSON( "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/journeymanavi/mock-json-api/posts", function( data ) { 
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data); 
    //document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = myObj.title; 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: `getJSON` will have already parsed the passed in data.  That's the whole pont of using it.  Remove your `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Also going to your endpoint, your title will actually be accessed by `data[0].title`

Comment: When putting in code, make sure you hit enter to separate it from the rest of your text and then indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

since myObj is not a variable initialized anywhere you need to use data instead. Also this contains an array so you can't just use '.title' but instead need to select the first element of the array and then title: '[0].title'
So it should look like this:

```
$.getJSON( "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/journeymanavi/mock-json-api/posts", function( data ) { 
    document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = data[0].title; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. I'm new in javascript so some mistakes happen.

Comment: When I'm fetching data value published-on is shown error Uncaught ReferenceError: on is not defined. document.getElementById("published").innerHTML = data[0].published-on;